# Is there any length limitation of result by "stats cachedump" in memcached?

Tags: memcached

I am trying to dump all my data from a running memcached instance.
But the result of command "stats cachedump" limit around 40000 lines which actually has more 100 million items, and my limit parameter is 1000 million.

Is there any other config limits this result length?
I tried this command during the php memcached client and telnet console, it sees to be the memcached server's limitation, because both of the results are limited around 40000.

Comment: After I wrote my question SO showed this question as _Related_. Therefore I comment it. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378640/memcached-how-to-break-the-limitation-when-retrieving-all-keys) is my post and a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I have found out the limitation reason.

There is a max dump size in the memcached source code, which is 2M, and hard to change.
I am looking for other ways to dump the whole cache data without stopping the application instance.

I have no idea how does memcached collect the top 2M keys during dumping. I have tried to dump it for several times and get different key lists.

See also [answer on mail list](http://lists.danga.com/pipermail/memcached/2007-April/003906.html)