# Memcached: How to break the limitation when retrieving all keys

Tags: php, memcached

Due to the fact I could not find any reliable program in the net which retrieves all memcache keys once the key count in a slab > 500k I wanted to write my own program in PHP.

Then I realized there is a reason why all of the programs did not really work for this high amount of keys.

When I read the keys with `stats cachedump <slab-id> <limit>` it returns only a certain amount of keys which ends - in my case - by around 30k.

How can I get at least these 500k which may be in one slab?

All the "posts" and "answers" which suggest to use `memdump` do not work. They have this limitation as well.

I am using `memcached 1.4.25`

Comment: NOTE: From my findings `stats cachedump ....` is only supported by the text-protocol versions of memcached (eg. when connecting to memcached via telnet or client library). If you're using modern memcached configuration with binary protocol (and SASL) then it seems it is impossible to run things like `stats cachedump 1 100`. Hence it seems that when using binary protocol you cannot neither call get-all-keys neither cachedump

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After debugging the `memcached` source I realized the limitation is in `items.c`/ `item_cachedump()` caused by this line:

```
unsigned int memlimit = 2 * 1024 * 1024;   /* 2MB max response size */
```

Due to this assignment the allocated buffer limits the amount of the returned keys because the total length of all keys [including `\r\n` after each key name] **must not** exceed this size.

I could solve for my case the problem in that way that I changed it to:

```
unsigned int memlimit = 128 * 1024 * 1024;
```

and recompiling `memcached`. Now I can read around 700k keys [I did not have more keys to max the function].

I found out that a very high value makes the system instable. With a value of `500 * 1024 * 1024` [e.q. 500MB] my system almost crashed with this messages:

> shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access
>   parent directories: No such file or directory

Even my server has 5GB RAM I don't really understand why but in the end a value of 128MB is a usable value.

I asked the `memcached` [developer team](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/issues/153) to add a switch which can set the value in the command line.