# getAllKeys() not returning all keys

Tags: php, memcached

Im trying to use `getAllKeys()` to return all keys from a memcached instance.

I tested by adding ~290000 keys and values.
Running `stats` on memcached, gives me the following output:

```
...
STAT curr_items 290264
STAT total_items 290264
...
```

However, when calling `getAllKeys()`, I only get 95832 returned.

Why is this?

- PHP v7.0.32
- memcached 3.0.4
- libmemcached 1.0.18

Comment: It may be because of the memlimit. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36379561/2191252 This may help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue with a combination of the above comment (upping the mem limit for getAllKeys and recompiling) and upping the overall mem limit of memcached.